# Failed to get Token DrEdit android sample

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to run the drive sdk android sample [DrEdit](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/android) , but I'm getting an exception:

```
04-23 16:49:19.642: E/DriveSyncAdapter(11914): Failed to get token
04-23 16:49:19.642: W/System.err(11914): com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission
04-23 16:49:19.642: W/System.err(11914):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
04-23 16:49:19.642: W/System.err(11914):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
04-23 16:49:19.642: W/System.err(11914):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:192)
04-23 16:49:19.642: W/System.err(11914):    at com.example.android.notepad.DriveSyncer.getDriveService(DriveSyncer.java:381)
04-23 16:49:19.642: W/System.err(11914):    at com.example.android.notepad.DriveSyncer.<init>(DriveSyncer.java:94)
04-23 16:49:19.642: W/System.err(11914):    at com.example.android.notepad.DriveSyncAdapter.onPerformSync(DriveSyncAdapter.java:32)
04-23 16:49:19.642: W/System.err(11914):    at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:254)
```

On:

```
credential.getToken();
```

In DriveSyncer.getDriveService().

I've already changed my Id in the manifest, and set the appropriated permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
   ...
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
      android:value="id=XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
```

And also enabled the drive API and set the credentials.

In my Android device, it asks me the account but never asks for the other authorization, it shows the notification but that's all. However, the quickstart sample runs perfectly.

The code where I'm getting the error is:

```
      private Drive getDriveService() {
        if (mService == null) {
          try {
            GoogleAccountCredential credential =
                GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(mContext, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
            credential.setSelectedAccountName(mAccount.name);
            // Trying to get a token right away to see if we are authorized
            credential.getToken();
            Log.e("MyTag", "Never Called");
            mService = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get token");
                    // If the Exception is User Recoverable, we display a notification that will trigger the
                    // intent to fix the issue.
                    if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
                        UserRecoverableAuthException exception = (UserRecoverableAuthException) e;
(NotificationManager) mContext
                            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        Intent authorizationIntent = exception.getIntent();
                        authorizationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(
                            Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0,
                            authorizationIntent, 0);
                        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .setTicker("Permission requested")
                            .setContentTitle("Permission requested")
                            .setContentText("for account " + mAccount.name)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true).build();
                        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
        return mService;
      }
```

Any ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with an HTC phone (Android 4.0.3), although it works fine on my Nexus 4. Fragmented Android SDK problems most likely.

Comment: It might be, because other drive or Google services samples work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem even I only run the original DrEdit. The permission request shows on the notification bar, but no response after I click it.

PS. I used the HTC 4.0.1 and Google phone to try this problem, but no one works.

Anyway, this article solved my problem, You can try this on. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16535080/1645840

The only different is I called this function, And it still works.

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification(mContext,
                    mAccount.name, "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE,
                    null);//, mAuthority, mSyncBundle);
```